# How to fix freezing my pc by Nvidia RTX 2060?

Tags: nvidia

I checked RAM healthy and it's fine but i think the problem is on NVIDIA RTX 2060 Graphic card.

My computer freezes completely randomly and no button works except power. This could be due to the RAM, but I tested the RAM and everything was working properly. My only doubt is about the graphics card that I just bought. Meanwhile, I am using Nvidia 535 driver.

Meanwhile, I am using two monitors and have connected both of them to the graphics card using the HTMI port. This situation is very annoying for me. Please help me if anyone has a similar experience.

How can i find the problem? How can i fix it?

Please read the log of syslog after freezing:

```
Aug 22 09:39:18 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5038]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-4:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    0.662934] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.094738] audit: type=1400 audit(1692706512.259:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=681 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.094740] audit: type=1400 audit(1692706512.259:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=681 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.305128] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.305136] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.315268] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.357109] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 234
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.357945] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.421367] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  535.86.05  Fri Jul 14 20:20:58 UTC 2023
Aug 22 15:45:12 masoud kernel: [    6.430071] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud kernel: [    7.043529] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud kernel: [    7.384463] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud kernel: [    7.407601] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud kernel: [    7.428596] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 510.
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud nvidia-persistenced: Now running with user ID 128 and group ID 138
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud nvidia-persistenced: Started (1298)
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud nvidia-persistenced: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
Aug 22 15:45:13 masoud nvidia-persistenced: Local RPC services initialized
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card0
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: #011loading driver: nvidia
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card0
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-4:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (WW) NVIDIA:     '/var/run/nvidia-xdriver-0a6b1852' Permission denied
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-4:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
Aug 22 15:45:14 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1524]: (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card0
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: #011loading driver: nvidia
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card0
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-4:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (WW) NVIDIA:     '/var/run/nvidia-xdriver-fcd52899' Permission denied
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-4:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
Aug 22 15:46:13 masoud /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5185]: (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.951252] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.951301] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.951322] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.951339] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.984328] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.984376] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.984397] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.984414] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.996055] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.996118] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.996138] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Aug 22 15:46:16 masoud kernel: [   70.996155] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```